# "take off with my clothes" or "take off my clothes"

Tags: prepositions

It's from [Friends(S02E13)](http://www.friendstranscripts.tk)

> She took off with my clothes

Why did it add *with* in it? It's very odd to me. How about "She took off my clothes?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a *huge* difference :)

> She took off my clothes.

Means that she undressed me.

> She took off *with* my clothes.

Means that she took off (left the premises) with my clothes (taking my clothes with her).

So though in both cases you might end up without clothes on, in the first case she's there with you (and it might imply interesting consequences), in the second case, you are undressed, and you have no clothes to put on. She is also no longer present.

Comment: Yes, _took off_ is a phrasal verb; another way to paraphrase the O.P.'s sentence is: _She ran away with my clothes._ Also, a minor point – you're not necessarily undressed when she takes off with your clothes (she might have took off with your gym bag, for example, in other words: _I left my gym bag in the back of her car, and she took off with my [change of] clothes_).

Comment: Correct! I added a minor _might_ :)